# Ansible Runner fails with `No Module named Azure.cli`

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, ansible

I have `azure-cli-core` installed but the playbook fails when trying to import `from azure.cli.core.auth.adal_authentication import MSIAuthenticationWrapper` from `/root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py`.

I've also tested by installing `azure.cli` but I still get the same error. There is no virtual env.

This issue happens only with `ansible-runner` though.

```
sh-4.4# pip3 list | grep azure.cli
azure-cli-core                          2.34.0
azure-cli-nspkg                         3.0.2
azure-cli-telemetry                     1.0.6



sh-4.4# head -1 $(which pip)
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
sh-4.4# head -1 $(which ansible-playbook)
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
sh-4.4# head -1 $(which ansible-runner)
#!/usr/libexec/platform-python
```

Error:

```
File \"/tmp/ansible_azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info_payload_xyanj4lw/ansible_azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info_payload.zip/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\", line 232, in <module>\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m    from azure.cli.core.auth.adal_authentication import MSIAuthenticationWrapper\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31mModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cli'
```

Full Log:

```
cat ansible-runner20220802-298-ji5oxn/artifacts/result/stdout
    [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Ansible will require Python 3.8 or newer on the
    controller starting with Ansible 2.12. Current version: 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14
    2022, 11:04:20) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-7)]. This feature will be
    removed from ansible-core in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled
     by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py:44: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography and will be removed in a future release.
      from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature
    ansible-playbook [core 2.11.12]
      config file = /root/.ansible.cfg
      configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
      ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
      ansible collection location = /root/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
      executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook
      python version = 3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2022, 11:04:20) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-7)]
      jinja version = 3.0.3
      libyaml = True
    Using /root/.ansible.cfg as config file
    host_list declined parsing /tmp/ansible-runner20220802-298-ji5oxn/inventory/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
    script declined parsing /tmp/ansible-runner20220802-298-ji5oxn/inventory/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
    auto declined parsing /tmp/ansible-runner20220802-298-ji5oxn/inventory/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() methodParsed /tmp/ansible-runner20220802-298-ji5oxn/inventory/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
    [WARNING]: While constructing a mapping from /tmp/ansible-runner-
    git20220802-298-9tlhvt/azure_sg_create.yaml, line 36, column 7, found a
    duplicate dict key (azure_vm_network_interface). Using last defined value only.
    redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.azure_rm_networkinterface_info to azure.azcollection.azure_rm_networkinterface_info
    redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.azure_rm_securitygroup to azure.azcollection.azure_rm_securitygroup
    redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.azure_rm_securitygroup to azure.azcollection.azure_rm_securitygroup
    redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.azure_rm_resource_info to azure.azcollection.azure_rm_resource_info
    redirecting (type: modules) ansible.builtin.azure_rm_networkinterface to azure.azcollection.azure_rm_networkinterface
    {"uuid": "731cb325-054e-4dfe-a8cb-0f093920f0ef", "counter": 30, "stdout": "\u001b[0;34mSkipping callback 'awx_display', as we already have a stdout callback.\u001b[0m", "start_line": 29, "end_line": 30, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "verbose", "pid": 31130, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.323222", "verbosity": 2, "event_data": {"verbose": true, "uuid": "731cb325-054e-4dfe-a8cb-0f093920f0ef"}}
    {"uuid": "cc48b9ae-1a15-4476-bb9c-cda5261dd8ad", "counter": 31, "stdout": "\u001b[0;34mSkipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.\u001b[0m", "start_line": 30, "end_line": 31, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "verbose", "pid": 31130, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.323647", "verbosity": 2, "event_data": {"verbose": true, "uuid": "cc48b9ae-1a15-4476-bb9c-cda5261dd8ad"}}
    {"uuid": "332162de-d104-49aa-a252-bb32cfdd055c", "counter": 32, "stdout": "\u001b[0;34mSkipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.\u001b[0m", "start_line": 31, "end_line": 32, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "verbose", "pid": 31130, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.323941", "verbosity": 2, "event_data": {"verbose": true, "uuid": "332162de-d104-49aa-a252-bb32cfdd055c"}}
    {"uuid": "f767a8ec-9a2a-44f3-88a4-4097ed57fc4a", "counter": 33, "stdout": "\u001b[0;34mSkipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.\u001b[0m", "start_line": 32, "end_line": 33, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "verbose", "pid": 31130, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.324215", "verbosity": 2, "event_data": {"verbose": true, "uuid": "f767a8ec-9a2a-44f3-88a4-4097ed57fc4a"}}
    {"uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "counter": 34, "stdout": "\r\nPLAYBOOK: azure_sg_create.yaml *************************************************", "start_line": 33, "end_line": 35, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "playbook_on_start", "pid": 31130, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.324527", "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f"}}
    {"uuid": "7d5951d3-e11a-4952-bda3-18f75ed4ac22", "counter": 35, "stdout": "\u001b[0;34m1 plays in azure_sg_create.yaml\u001b[0m", "start_line": 35, "end_line": 36, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "verbose", "pid": 31130, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.324848", "parent_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "verbosity": 2, "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "verbose": true, "uuid": "7d5951d3-e11a-4952-bda3-18f75ed4ac22"}}
    {"uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "counter": 36, "stdout": "\r\nPLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************", "start_line": 36, "end_line": 38, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "playbook_on_play_start", "pid": 31130, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.328944", "parent_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "play": "localhost", "play_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "play_pattern": "localhost", "name": "localhost", "pattern": "localhost", "uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006"}}
    {"uuid": "d234c4c3-1a21-427b-9970-a4c54a6810e2", "counter": 37, "stdout": "\u001b[0;34mMETA: ran handlers\u001b[0m", "start_line": 38, "end_line": 39, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "verbose", "pid": 31130, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.342207", "parent_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "verbosity": 2, "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "play": "localhost", "play_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "play_pattern": "localhost", "verbose": true, "uuid": "d234c4c3-1a21-427b-9970-a4c54a6810e2"}}
    {"uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "counter": 38, "stdout": "\r\nTASK [Get facts by name] *******************************************************\r\n\u001b[1;30mtask path: /tmp/ansible-runner-git20220802-298-9tlhvt/azure_sg_create.yaml:18\u001b[0m", "start_line": 39, "end_line": 42, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "playbook_on_task_start", "pid": 31130, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.356963", "parent_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "play": "localhost", "play_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "play_pattern": "localhost", "task": "Get facts by name", "task_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "task_action": "azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info", "task_args": "", "task_path": "/tmp/ansible-runner-git20220802-298-9tlhvt/azure_sg_create.yaml:18", "name": "Get facts by name", "is_conditional": false, "uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008"}}
    {"uuid": "ac3000a2-5f53-4fd2-934b-ec9a82ef311d", "counter": 39, "stdout": "", "start_line": 42, "end_line": 42, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "runner_on_start", "pid": 31130, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.357658", "parent_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "play": "localhost", "play_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "play_pattern": "localhost", "task": "Get facts by name", "task_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "task_action": "azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info", "task_args": "", "task_path": "/tmp/ansible-runner-git20220802-298-9tlhvt/azure_sg_create.yaml:18", "host": "localhost", "uuid": "ac3000a2-5f53-4fd2-934b-ec9a82ef311d"}}
    {"uuid": "9635bad0-e2b8-4201-905b-edd3cef98d92", "counter": 40, "stdout": "\u001b[0;34m<localhost> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root\u001b[0m", "start_line": 42, "end_line": 43, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "verbose", "pid": 31181, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.372856", "parent_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "verbosity": 3, "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "play": "localhost", "play_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "play_pattern": "localhost", "task": "Get facts by name", "task_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "task_action": "azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info", "task_args": "", "task_path": "/tmp/ansible-runner-git20220802-298-9tlhvt/azure_sg_create.yaml:18", "verbose": true, "remote_addr": "localhost", "uuid": "9635bad0-e2b8-4201-905b-edd3cef98d92"}}
    {"uuid": "fb88ed54-8537-4a17-894b-c48b400715bb", "counter": 41, "stdout": "\u001b[0;34m<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo /tmp/.ansible_remote_tmp `\"&& mkdir \"` echo /tmp/.ansible_remote_tmp/ansible-tmp-1659427465.3725164-31181-178678518794551 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1659427465.3725164-31181-178678518794551=\"` echo /tmp/.ansible_remote_tmp/ansible-tmp-1659427465.3725164-31181-178678518794551 `\" ) && sleep 0'\u001b[0m", "start_line": 43, "end_line": 44, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "verbose", "pid": 31181, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.373430", "parent_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "verbosity": 3, "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "play": "localhost", "play_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "play_pattern": "localhost", "task": "Get facts by name", "task_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "task_action": "azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info", "task_args": "", "task_path": "/tmp/ansible-runner-git20220802-298-9tlhvt/azure_sg_create.yaml:18", "verbose": true, "remote_addr": "localhost", "uuid": "fb88ed54-8537-4a17-894b-c48b400715bb"}}
    {"uuid": "278b8b60-b3cc-4bfe-a7c3-4a32710f86b5", "counter": 42, "stdout": "\u001b[0;34mUsing module file /root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/modules/azure_rm_virtualmachine_info.py\u001b[0m", "start_line": 44, "end_line": 45, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "verbose", "pid": 31181, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.510704", "parent_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "verbosity": 3, "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "play": "localhost", "play_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "play_pattern": "localhost", "task": "Get facts by name", "task_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "task_action": "azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info", "task_args": "", "task_path": "/tmp/ansible-runner-git20220802-298-9tlhvt/azure_sg_create.yaml:18", "verbose": true, "uuid": "278b8b60-b3cc-4bfe-a7c3-4a32710f86b5"}}{"uuid": "7ed9952f-b1a1-43bc-981f-7c660c0dcefb", "counter": 43, "stdout": "\u001b[0;34m<localhost> PUT /tmp/.ansible_local_tmp/ansible-local-31130hl2ez_g5/tmpaf06u864 TO /tmp/.ansible_remote_tmp/ansible-tmp-1659427465.3725164-31181-178678518794551/AnsiballZ_azure_rm_virtualmachine_info.py\u001b[0m", "start_line": 45, "end_line": 46, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "verbose", "pid": 31181, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.511422", "parent_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "verbosity": 3, "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "play": "localhost", "play_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "play_pattern": "localhost", "task": "Get facts by name", "task_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "task_action": "azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info", "task_args": "", "task_path": "/tmp/ansible-runner-git20220802-298-9tlhvt/azure_sg_create.yaml:18", "verbose": true, "remote_addr": "localhost", "uuid": "7ed9952f-b1a1-43bc-981f-7c660c0dcefb"}}
    {"uuid": "b5aeca89-e0a1-410b-8422-7e3ff7f2a8fd", "counter": 44, "stdout": "\u001b[0;34m<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /tmp/.ansible_remote_tmp/ansible-tmp-1659427465.3725164-31181-178678518794551/ /tmp/.ansible_remote_tmp/ansible-tmp-1659427465.3725164-31181-178678518794551/AnsiballZ_azure_rm_virtualmachine_info.py && sleep 0'\u001b[0m", "start_line": 46, "end_line": 47, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "verbose", "pid": 31181, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.512097", "parent_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "verbosity": 3, "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "play": "localhost", "play_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "play_pattern": "localhost", "task": "Get facts by name", "task_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "task_action": "azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info", "task_args": "", "task_path": "/tmp/ansible-runner-git20220802-298-9tlhvt/azure_sg_create.yaml:18", "verbose": true, "remote_addr": "localhost", "uuid": "b5aeca89-e0a1-410b-8422-7e3ff7f2a8fd"}}
    {"uuid": "d2a9dfdd-f21e-4bd5-9e04-2e46bedd9160", "counter": 45, "stdout": "\u001b[0;34m<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/bin/python3 /tmp/.ansible_remote_tmp/ansible-tmp-1659427465.3725164-31181-178678518794551/AnsiballZ_azure_rm_virtualmachine_info.py && sleep 0'\u001b[0m", "start_line": 47, "end_line": 48, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "verbose", "pid": 31181, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.518275", "parent_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "verbosity": 3, "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "play": "localhost", "play_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "play_pattern": "localhost", "task": "Get facts by name", "task_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "task_action": "azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info", "task_args": "", "task_path": "/tmp/ansible-runner-git20220802-298-9tlhvt/azure_sg_create.yaml:18", "verbose": true, "remote_addr": "localhost", "uuid": "d2a9dfdd-f21e-4bd5-9e04-2e46bedd9160"}}
    {"uuid": "c30eec8b-d8c4-459e-99d8-02f6161b97cb", "counter": 46, "stdout": "\u001b[0;34m<localhost> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /tmp/.ansible_remote_tmp/ansible-tmp-1659427465.3725164-31181-178678518794551/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'\u001b[0m", "start_line": 48, "end_line": 49, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "verbose", "pid": 31181, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.989405", "parent_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "verbosity": 3, "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "play": "localhost", "play_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "play_pattern": "localhost", "task": "Get facts by name", "task_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "task_action": "azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info", "task_args": "", "task_path": "/tmp/ansible-runner-git20220802-298-9tlhvt/azure_sg_create.yaml:18", "verbose": true, "remote_addr": "localhost", "uuid": "c30eec8b-d8c4-459e-99d8-02f6161b97cb"}}
    {"uuid": "7a50cc6f-20e7-450c-bf6f-60cb53dac8c9", "counter": 47, "stdout": "\u001b[0;31mThe full traceback is:\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31mTraceback (most recent call last):\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info_payload_xyanj4lw/ansible_azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info_payload.zip/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\", line 232, in <module>\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m    from azure.cli.core.auth.adal_authentication import MSIAuthenticationWrapper\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31mModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cli'\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31mfatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m    \"changed\": false,\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m    \"invocation\": {\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m        \"module_args\": {\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"ad_user\": null,\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"adfs_authority_url\": null,\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"api_profile\": \"latest\",\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"auth_source\": \"auto\",\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"cert_validation_mode\": null,\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"client_id\": null,\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"cloud_environment\": \"AzureCloud\",\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"log_mode\": null,\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"log_path\": null,\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"name\": \"Ubuntu967\",\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"password\": null,\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"profile\": null,\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"resource_group\": \"cloud-shell-storage-centralindia\",\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"secret\": null,\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"subscription_id\": null,\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"tags\": null,\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m            \"tenant\": null\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m        }\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m    },\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m    \"msg\": \"Failed to import the required Python library (ansible[azure] (azure >= 2.0.0)) on a3b2d24ea52b's Python /bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter\"\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[0;31m}\u001b[0m", "start_line": 49, "end_line": 79, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "runner_on_failed", "pid": 31130, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.998738", "parent_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "play": "localhost", "play_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000006", "play_pattern": "localhost", "task": "Get facts by name", "task_uuid": "0242ac11-0002-db10-30e1-000000000008", "task_action": "azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info", "task_args": "", "task_path": "/tmp/ansible-runner-git20220802-298-9tlhvt/azure_sg_create.yaml:18", "host": "localhost", "remote_addr": "localhost", "res": {"exception": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info_payload_xyanj4lw/ansible_azure.azcollection.azure_rm_virtualmachine_info_payload.zip/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/plugins/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\", line 232, in <module>\n    from azure.cli.core.auth.adal_authentication import MSIAuthenticationWrapper\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cli'\n", "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (ansible[azure] (azure >= 2.0.0)) on a3b2d24ea52b's Python /bin/python3. Please read the module documentation and install it in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter", "invocation": {"module_args": {"resource_group": "cloud-shell-storage-centralindia", "name": "Ubuntu967", "auth_source": "auto", "cloud_environment": "AzureCloud", "api_profile": "latest", "profile": null, "subscription_id": null, "client_id": null, "secret": null, "tenant": null, "ad_user": null, "password": null, "cert_validation_mode": null, "adfs_authority_url": null, "log_mode": null, "log_path": null, "tags": null}}, "_ansible_no_log": false, "changed": false, "_ansible_delegated_vars": {"ansible_host": "localhost", "ansible_port": null, "ansible_user": "ubuntu", "ansible_connection": "local"}}, "start": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.357589", "end": "2022-08-02T08:04:25.998540", "duration": 0.640951, "ignore_errors": null, "event_loop": null, "uuid": "7a50cc6f-20e7-450c-bf6f-60cb53dac8c9"}}
    {"uuid": "0755fbe8-b6ec-4ebd-a4d4-1940305e7ccb", "counter": 48, "stdout": "\r\nPLAY RECAP *********************************************************************\r\n\u001b[0;31mlocalhost\u001b[0m                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    \u001b[0;31mfailed=1   \u001b[0m skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   \r\n", "start_line": 79, "end_line": 83, "runner_ident": "result", "event": "playbook_on_stats", "pid": 31130, "created": "2022-08-02T08:04:26.000735", "parent_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "event_data": {"playbook": "azure_sg_create.yaml", "playbook_uuid": "0049f739-955c-4a6d-a47e-1e84b431ba4f", "changed": {}, "dark": {}, "failures": {"localhost": 1}, "ignored": {}, "ok": {}, "processed": {"localhost": 1}, "rescued": {}, "skipped": {}, "artifact_data": {}, "uuid": "0755fbe8-b6ec-4ebd-a4d4-1940305e7ccb"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow to resolve the above issue;

> cat ansible-runner20220802-298-ji5oxn/artifacts/result/stdout
> [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Ansible will require Python 3.8 or newer on the
> controller starting with Ansible 2.12. Current version: 3.6.8

Based on this [***GitHub***](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/70300#issuecomment-662905470) issue

> **For the error try to uninstall all of the above ansible ,python and**
> **cli . And install the ansible by using below `cmdlts`:-**
>
> ```
> pip3 install ansible
> ```

*For more information please refer this* [***Ansible Documentation***](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/70300#issuecomment-662905470).